# Android studio uses wrong file path to apk when I use custom build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

So Im trying to use a custom build file that generates an unsigned apk then runs a task on it and then zipaligns it. I havent gotten that working yet. However I do have it creating and properly signing the apk but when I try to just push the play button to run it in debug on a device using my custom debug set up studio/gradle generates my apk and places it in the directory I want but it fails to push it on to the device because it uses a file path that doesnt exist. 
I/O Error: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio\apk\V2.5-10-debug-20140922-2335.apk (The system cannot find the path specified). Is this hard coded into the studio build because I cant find a setting to change it. Its really making the whole process a real pain lol. Infact that path doesnt exist anywhere on my machine.

**EDIT**  heres my build.gradle file

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


def buildTime() {
    def df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'-'HHmm")
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())
    return df.format(new Date())
}

def apkName = "MyApp"
def apkLocation

task (runApkSigTool , dependsOn: android, type: JavaExec) {

    classpath files('apksigtool.jar')
    main 'com.widevine.tools.android.apksigtool.ApkSigTool'
    args[0] = apkLocation
    args[1] = 'private_key.der'
    args[2] = 'my.crt'
    System.out.println(apkLocation);
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"


signingConfigs{

    debug{
        storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        storePassword "android"
        keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
        keyPassword "android"

    }

    release{
        storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        storePassword "android"
        keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
        keyPassword "android"

    }

}


buildTypes {

    debug{

    }

    release {

    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    runProguard false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    assembleDebug.doLast{
       runApkSigTool.execute()
    }

    zipAlign true

}

debug{

    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    runProguard false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    assembleDebug.doLast{
        runApkSigTool.execute()
    }

    zipAlign false

}


android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    def manifestFile = file("C:\\path\\app\\src\\main\\AndroidManifest.xml")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionName=\"(.+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    def versionName = matcher.group(1)
    pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(.+)\"")
    matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    def versionCode = matcher.group(1)

    if (variant.zipAlign) {
        variant.outputFile = new File("apk/"+apkName+"-V"+versionName+"-"+versionCode+"-"+variant.name+"-"+buildTime()+"-unaligned.apk");
        variant.zipAlign.inputFile = variant.outputFile
        variant.zipAlign.outputFile = new File("apk/"+apkName+"-V"+versionName+"-"+versionCode+"-"+variant.name+"-"+buildTime()+".apk");
    } else {

        apkLocation = "apk/"+apkName+"-V"+versionName+"-"+versionCode+"-"+variant.name+"-"+buildTime()+".apk";
        variant.outputFile = new File("apk/"+apkName+"-V"+versionName+"-"+versionCode+"-"+variant.name+"-"+buildTime()+".apk");

        System.out.println("CREATED UNSIGNED APK---------------")

    }

}

}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    ignoreWarnings true
    checkAllWarnings false
 }



}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:20.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
}
```

Comment: can you provide your build.gradle file content. It´s not possible to reproduce this issue without more information

Comment: Android Studio queries Gradle to get the output file of the variant it wants to install. In your code you're giving the variant a relative path, which is getting you into trouble -- don't assume anything about the working directory when the command runs. Instead, anchor the directory to the module's root directory. I'm not sure your `variant.outputFile` stuff is working properly, even then -- your error message (which shows a path relative to Android Studio's install dir) is pointing at a filename that doesn't follow the convention in your code. So something else is going wrong.

Comment: I think the variant.output stuff is working because otherwise I wouldnt get build apk files in my apk directory I created. When you say anchor the directory to the modules root do you mean where the src and res folders are in the project? My apk directory is already in my projects root. Should I just let gradle place the file in the project root without the apk directory?

Comment: When it builds, it's running in a different context (with a different working directory) than when Android Studio executes the build file to extract information about the project. It's your use of a pure relative path that's not anchored to anything that's one cause of problems.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. How should I go about creating the unsigned apk then. Should I just use file with no path declaration?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but without using any hardcoded path...

Answer (score 0):

installDebug is calling buildTime() too when preparing the adb push command so the dates would mismatch with every minute.